# Java Loops and which one to use correctly

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I have a question regarding java programming specifically with loops. This program I am needing to write, requires a loop that will sort three books based of the order of the year published. Would I use a for-loop for this? I'm extremely new to java programming so any input would be helpful. If possible could someone give me an example of a loop created like the one stated above.

Comment: This has to be an assignment. So show us what you've tried. Presumably your course has covered some java features. What loops have been mentioned? Write out how you would sort them manually, in English, then code that?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you dont need a loop for this.  Try the following:

1. create a class that represents the thing to be sorted (book).
2. inplement Comparable on that class.
3. Create a List of objects to be sorted.
4. Sort using Collections.sort(blammy)

Comment: While relatively simple, this may be too complicated a solution for someone learning simple looping.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a while loop here to say

```
while(books > 0) {
//execute sorting code here

}
```

and then it will execute the code until no more books

Answer (score 0):

You can use bubble sort for that, it is the easiest to understand sorting algorythm for all programming languages.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer. Some users post homework or write this code for me style questions. In these cases the community usually redirects users to show their code so that the community can help assist with any road block.